# MySQL Event Scheduler on a specific time every Saturday

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler

Here's my query

```
    CREATE EVENT saturday
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 6 DAY
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  DO UPDATE `AttrInfo`.`attrID` SET `4` =  '2000';
```

Idea behind is that it will double the value for Saturday, and then I need to find a way for it to change the value back to 1000 when Sunday starts.

[image from the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN8JQ.png)

AttrInfo = table

attr1 = column

4 = row

value = 2000

Comment: You can create as any events as you like so I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: Just do the doubling when querying the data. You can use a `CASE` expression to check if it's Saturday and then double the value or else leave it as it is. You can create a view that does that, so that you don't need to repeat it every time.